# Solving inverse matrix from equation.

Tags: matrices

let matrix $A$ be
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
Calculate B: when, $s \in \Bbb{R}$ \ {${2,1}$}

$$B=(sI-A)^{-1}$$

I know how to calculate inverse matrix of a matrix for example $A^{-1}$ but with this kind of equation i have no clue where to begin with. Would be great if someone could point me in right direction.

Comment: Have you tried writing out what sI - A is?

Comment: Another thing that i dont understand in this that what is $s$ ? and $I$ stands for identity matrix $$I=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @Tuki, $s$ is just a real number other than $1$ and $2$.

Comment: So the equation would look like this ? $$(s\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix})^{-1}$$ $$(\begin{bmatrix}s & 0 \\ 0 & s \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix})^{-1}$$

Comment: Yes you are right. And you will see that $\begin{bmatrix}s & 0 \\ 0 & s \end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 2 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$ the rows/columns are linear dependent for $s=1,2$. In this case it cannot be inverted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$sI-A=\begin{bmatrix}s-2 & -2 \\ 0 & s-1 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\implies A^{-1}=\frac1{ad-bc}\begin{bmatrix}d & -b \\ -c & a \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: How does the $A^{-1}$ help for the exercise ?

Comment: @callculus The question asks to compute the inverse of $A'=(Is-A)$. Now rename $A$ and $A'$ and we can use the formula.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In this way it makes sense. But without the renaming it´s confusing.

Comment: I can use this formula for $$B = (\begin{bmatrix}s-2 & -2 \\ 0 & s-1 \end{bmatrix})^{-1}$$ $$B = \begin{bmatrix} s-1 & -(-2) \\ -(0) & s-2 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Seems like this isn't correct

Comment: Any idea why $$B=\begin{bmatrix} s-1 & 2 \\ 0 & s-2 \end{bmatrix}$$ is not correct ?

Comment: You are forgetting to divide by $ad-bc$.